# Why are the descendants of Hebron not specifically named in Exodus 6:17-22?

Tags: exodus, numbers, genealogy

Exodus 6:17-22 KJV

> 17 The sons of Gershon;  Libni, and Shimi, according to their families.   18 And the sons of Kohath;  Amram, and Izhar, and ***Hebron***, and Uzziel:  and the years of the life of Kohath were an hundred thirty and three years.   19 And the sons of Merari;  Mahali and Mushi:  these are the families of Levi according to their generations.   20 And Amram took him Jochebed his father's sister to wife;  and she bare him Aaron and Moses:  and the years of the life of Amram were an hundred and thirty and seven years.   21 And the sons of Izhar;  Korah, and Nepheg, and Zichri.   22 And the sons of Uzziel;  Mishael, and Elzaphan, and Zithri.

The sons of Hebron are not specifically named whilst all his brothers sons are mentioned by name,although later his descendants are just called the Hebronites.

Numbers 3:27 KJV

> 27 And of Kohath was the family of the Amramites, and the family of the Izeharites, and the family of the ***Hebronites***, and the family of the Uzzielites:  these are the families of the Kohathites.   28 In the number of all the males, from a month old and upward, were eight thousand and six hundred, keeping the charge of the sanctuary.

Numbers 26:58 KJV

> 58 These are the families of the Levites:  the family of the Libnites, the family of the ***Hebronites***, the family of the Mahlites, the family of the Mushites, the family of the Korathites.   And Kohath begat Amram

What could be reason for not mentioning his descendants by name?

Comment: The sons of the Indo-Europeans: the Slavs, the Germans, the Latins, the Indo-Iranians, the Greeks, the Albanians, the Armenians. The sons of the Slavs: the Eastern Slavs, the Western Slavs, the Southern Slavs. The sons of the Germans: the Western Germans, the Northern Germans. The sons of the Latins: the Western Latins, the Eastern Latins. The sons of the Indo-Iranians: the Indians, the Iranians. Now, *why do you think that the preceding list does not include the sons of the last three groups ?*